# Change all items price in cart with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cart, webshop

I am creating a webshop for a rental company. I want to be able to change the price of items according to amount of days they rent the item. I was already able to get the amount of days, but not sure on how to change the price of an item.

This is my code so far in the cart controller.

The error I get is that $rowId is not defined.

```html
public function getTime(Request $request){
      $startD = Carbon::parse($request->input('dateOut'));
      $endD = Carbon::parse($request->input('dateIn'));
      $length = $endD->diffInDays($startD) + 1;
      $total = Cart::subtotal();
      $rows = Cart::count();

      for ($i=0; $i <$rows ; $i++) { 
        $item = Cart::get($rowId);

      Cart::update(
        $rowId, [ 
          'price' => $items->product_price*$length, 
        ]);
      }

      echo $startD;
      echo $endD;
      echo $length;
      echo $total;
    }
```

Comment: the error you are getting is because there is no where in your code you initialize the `$rowId` which you are using.

Comment: Are you using one of the Laravel shopping cart packages? If yes, which one?

Comment: Hi I am using the Gloudemans package. Thank for the quick answer.

Comment: I think I found the solution: foreach(Cart::content() as $row) {
      $rowid=$row->rowId;
      Cart::update(
        $rowid, [ 
          'price' => $row->model->price*$length, 
        ]);
      }

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating the price of a specific `cart`, then you can use such a query.

```
\DB::statement("update carts set price = ABS(`price` * datediff(?,?)) where id=?", [$dateOut, $dateIn, $cart_id]);
```